# Issues while using setConf in SparkLauncher from Windows

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to trigger Pyspark code using SparkLauncher from Windows.

When I use

```
.setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "1G")
```

or any other configuration, the following error message is thrown,

```
--conf "spark.driver.memory' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Also, I need to add multiple dependency jars. For example, when I use

```
addJar("D:\\jars\\elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.0.0-rc2.jar")
```

it is working. But when it is used multiple times

```
.addJar("D:\\jars\\elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.0.0-rc2.jar")
.addJar("D:\\jars\\mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar")
```

the following error is thrown

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The same code works in Linux environment.

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: How do you execute the code? Is this `spark-submit` or `pyspark` or...??? Could you share the entire command?